# How to animate a border with linear gradient but with transparent Background

Tags: javascript, css

I would like to animate the border of an element with a linear gradient; the element has a **transparent background**. To illustrate this, please see the following images:

[image]

[image]

The following is a solution that comes very close to my needs, but I can't remove the background.

```
.btn__get-tickets {
  padding: 10px;
  background: white;
  background-clip: content-box;
  position: relative;
}
.btn__get-tickets:after, .btn__get-tickets:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  content:'';
}
.btn__get-tickets:after {
  background: linear-gradient(140deg, #5bc7d3, #88ca43, #fdd207);
  z-index: -1;
  animation: test 5s ease infinite;
}
.btn__get-tickets:before {
  background: linear-gradient(120deg, #88ca43, #fdd207,#5bc7d3);
  z-index: -2;
}

@keyframes test {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

Next solution that comes also very close but has the same problem with the background:

https://codepen.io/pimmey/pen/NABQWX

Is it possible to animate the border-image property with Javascript?

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? StackOverflow isn't a free code-writing service, and expects you to [**try to solve your own problem first**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592). Please update your question to show what you have already tried, showcasing the specific problem you are facing in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For further information, please see [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [**tour**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) of the site :)

Comment: You might want to take a look at this CodePen example.https://codepen.io/ARS/pen/vEwEPP Mind you, a lot of implementations use some sort of a processor.

Comment: here is another example https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/pKwby or https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/IGliC . hint : animation on background-position and eventually background size

Comment: @KanstantsinArlouski: Very nice solution, but it uses clip-path. I need a greater Browser Support. Thanks for the Link!

Comment: @GCyrillus: Same problem with solid background.

Comment: example + hints are not solution . so bg-size+position+animation put together https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/XgzGgZ ;) needs your colors and tunning

Answer (score 2):

here is an example from gradient animated in the background to fake borders :

```css
button {
  vertical-align: top;
  border: none;
  padding: 15px;
  background: linear-gradient(
        to right,/* use every colors and repeat first one at the end*/
        #79c975,
        #5dc7cc,
        #fad108,
        #b9ce2b,
        #79c975
      )
      160%
      0
      repeat-x,
    linear-gradient(to top, #79c975, #5dc7cc, #fad108, #b9ce2b, #79c975)
      100%
      20%
      repeat-y,
    linear-gradient(to left, #79c975, #5dc7cc, #fad108, #b9ce2b, #79c975)
      10%
      100%
      repeat-x,
    linear-gradient(to bottom, #79c975, #5dc7cc, #fad108, #b9ce2b, #79c975)
      0%
      10%
      repeat-y;

  background-size: 300% 10px, 10px 300%;/* increase size to show at once the bit from 2 gradient colors */
  animation: bd 5s infinite linear;
}
@keyframes bd {
  50% {
    background-position: 460% 0, 100% 320%, 310% 100%, 0% 310%;/* average reset of bg-position , tune it to desired effect */
  }
}
body {
  background: gray;
}
```

```html
<button>button</button>
<button>and another button</button>
```

this would actually be a job for SVG

Comment: Hi, thanks for this. And you're so right with doing this with SVG. That's it.
So i found a very simple solution for that.

Answer (score 1):

finally the hint doing this with an animated SVG did the Job for me.

My Solution looks like this:

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn__get-tickets">Button</a>
```

SASS

```
.btn {
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: $white-button;
  border: 5px solid transparent;

  &.btn__get-tickets {
    border-image: url("images/test.svg");
    border-image-slice: 20;
  }
}
```

SVG

```
`<svg width="160" height="70">
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="linear" x1="50%" y1="0%" x2="50%" y2="100%">
      <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#7A5FFF">
        <animate attributeName="stop-color" values="#7A5FFF; #01FF89; #7A5FFF" dur="4s" repeatCount="indefinite"></animate>
      </stop>
      <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#01FF89">
        <animate attributeName="stop-color" values="#01FF89; #7A5FFF; #01FF89" dur="4s" repeatCount="indefinite"></animate>
      </stop>
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>
  <rect x="5" y="5" width="150" height="60" fill="url(#linear)"></rect>
</svg>`
```